# How to setup Spring JDBC Connection Pooling with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

Am using Spring Boot 1.5.4 with Spring JDBC.

Have a Spring Boot Microservice which uses Spring JDBC has the following issue when trying to conduct an HTTP PUT (after a bunch of users try conducting an HTTP PUT) which trickles to this Spring JDBC call:

```
2018-10-10 19:40:02 [http-nio-8081-exec-4] ERROR c.v.r.RepositoryImpl - Problem in updateData() method: 
"org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [select a.user_id,b.user_id, from user a join user_profile b where a.user_id=b.user_id and a.date=?;]; No operations allowed after connection closed.; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:79)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 28,915,589 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 9 milliseconds ago.
    at com.myapp.repository.RepositoryImpl.updateData(RepositoryImpl.java:74)
    at com.myapp.repository.RepositoryImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1be9dd8e.invoke(<generated>)
    ... 52 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2914)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3337)
    ... 83 common frames omitted
```

pom.xml:

```
<artifactId>MyService</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>   

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.33</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Am guessing that I need to setup a JDBC connection pool...

Inside my application.properties settings, (I have two different databases - one local and one remote, its losing connection with the remote database; database2):

```
# Local
spring.datasource.database1.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/database1?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
spring.datasource.database1.username=root
spring.datasource.database1.password=ret2my
spring.datasource.database1.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# Remote
spring.datasource.database2.url=jdbc:mysql://read-replica-database-production.cranmichpmc.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com/database2?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
spring.datasource.database2.username=root
spring.datasource.database2.password=ret2a$$
spring.datasource.database2.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Should I add this for the second database:

```
spring.datasource.database2.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
spring.datasource.database2.hikari.connection-timeout=60000
```

Are there other useful params that I should consider?

Answer (score 0):

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://10.168.143.140:3306/database_name
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=4
```

more detailed information can be found at : 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html

Comment: Thanks Ajay, am I using hikari? Should it be higher than 4?

Comment: you can use either tomcat or hikari.
max-pool depends on your application requirement and the number of database connections available.

Comment: sometimes it so happens that other programs may be holding onto the db connections and preventing your program from getting access to db connection resource. i would advice you to check the active client connections on db